# Не все элементы удаляются с массива

Tags: javascript

Почему один элемент остается в comments и как это исправить ?

```js
var ids = [200, 201];
var comments = [{
  id: 201
}, {
  id: 200
}];

comments.forEach(function(comment, index) {
  if (ids.includes(comment.id)) {
    comments.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

console.log(comments); // not empty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно быть осторожным при использовании функции [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) внутри цикла. Частая проблема - дырки в случае, когда удаляемые элементы идут подряд. Из-за изменения счетчика второй элемент для удаления просто пропускается.

Для фильтрации массива лучше использовать функцию [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
comments = comments.filter(function(comment){ 
    return !ids.includes(comment.id);
})
```

Если нужно использовать splice, то вместо [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach), в котором нет контроля над изменениями индекса, лучше использовать обычный [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for(var i=0;i<comments.length;){
    var comment = comments[i];
    if (ids.includes(comment.id)) {
        comments.splice(i, 1);
    }else{
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Так как при удалении элемента из середины индексы после удаленного сдвигаются, увеличивать счетчик нужно только для случая, когда удаления не было, это позволит предотвратить пропуск второго элемента удовлетворяющего условию.

Убрать ветку else и привести цикл в более привычный вид можно, если проверять элементы массива с конца:

```
for(var i=comments.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    var comment = comments[i];
    if (ids.includes(comment.id)) {
        comments.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```