# Удалить повторяющийся массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется массив

```
var a = [
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ]
];
```

Необходимо удалить массив который совпадает по доменному имени. Как это сделать?

Comment: в массивах всегда 4 элемента? значимый только четвертый?

Comment: нет не всегда. может быть и 3, 4, 5

Comment: Должны совпадать все элементы массива? либо какой-то конкретный?

Answer (score 1):

Внешний цикл делает обход по всем элементам массива, внутренний идёт от i-того элемента до конца, и добавляет в массив все индексы для удаления, а затем проходим по исходному массиву и копируем элементы в новый массив, но те, которые не вошли в `indexes`. Результат будет в `newArr`.

```
 indexes = []
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[i][3] == a[j][3]) {
            indexes.push(j);
        }
    }
 }
 newArr = []
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (indexes.indexOf(i) == -1) {
       newArr.push(a[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: плохое решение, со splice внутри цикла надо быть аккуратным. Если нужно будет удалить два элемента подряд - данный код - удалит только один

Comment: лучше не стало: удалив элемент с индексом 1 - у тебя сдвинуться индексы всех остальных элементов и ты поудаляешь не то

Comment: посмотри приемы использования splice в цикле. [в этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587608/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/587613#587613)

Comment: уже лучше, второй цикл можно на filter заменить

Comment: @Grundy, ну я остановлюсь на этом решении, оно отрабатывает правильно.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
    if (a[i][3] == a[j][3]) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
      i = 0;
      j = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var a = [
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ]
];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
    if (a[i][3] == a[j][3]) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
      i = 0;
      j = 0;
    }
  }
}
console.log(a)
```

Comment: а обнулять-то зачем переменные?

Comment: @Grundy если не обнулять, то splice сработает не корректно. Надо проходить еще раз после вхождения в if..

Comment: Обнулять совсем не обязательно, достаточно просто не увеличивать счетчик в случае когда было удаление.

Comment: @Grundy согласен, можно сделать '--' переменным.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var result = a.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (!acc.map[cur[3]]) { // если проверяемого элемента еще не было
    acc.map[cur[3]] = true; // пометим его, как существующий,
    acc.result.push(cur); // добавим в результирующий массив
  }
  return acc; // вернем аккумулятор
}, {
  map: {}, // хранит уникальные поля
  result: [] // хранит результирующий массив
}).result; // сохраняем в переменную результирующий массив
```

Пример в работе:

```js
var a = [
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ]
];

var result = a.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (!acc.map[cur[3]]) {
    acc.map[cur[3]] = true;
    acc.result.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  map: {},
  result: []
}).result;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Если нужно проверять полное совпадение массивов, вместо проверки конкретного элемента, можно отсортировать массив  привести к сторке - отсортированные массивы с одинаковыми элементами дадут одинакокую строку:

```
var result = a.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  var key = [...cur].sort();
  if (!acc.map[key]) {
    acc.map[key] = true;
    acc.result.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  map: {},
  result: []
}).result;
```

Пример:

```js
var a = [
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://yootube.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url",
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
  ],
  [
    "url",
    "url", // этот массив необходимо удалить так как доменные имена совпадают
    "url",
    "http://mall.aliexpress.com/"
  ]
];

var result = a.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  var key = [...cur].sort();
  if (!acc.map[key]) {
    acc.map[key] = true;
    acc.result.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  map: {},
  result: []
}).result;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```