# Как сгруппировать вложенные объекты с одинаковыми значениями свойств?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня.
Пытаюсь решить задачу:

Допустим, имеется объект с повторяющимися свойствами вложенных объектов:

```
var obj = {
    [0] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Белая'
    }
    [1] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Белая'
    }
    [2] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Черная'
    }
    [3] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Черная'
    }
    [4] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Серая'
    }
}
```

Необходимо на их основе выстроить новый объект такого вида:

```
var obj = {
    [0] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Белая',
        count: 2
    }
    [1] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Черная',
        count: 2
    }
    [2] = {
        title: 'Дверь',
        color: 'Серая',
        count: 1
    }
}
```

P.S. Значение свойства `title` может изменяться так же, как и `color`.

Comment: Отлично, где Ваше решение?

Comment: могу поспорить здесь замешан php! В яваскрипте все эти записи синтаксически неверны

Comment: @Grundy, лучше не придирайтесь к ошибке, а помогите - запросите цену, раз ТС думает что тут фриланс.

Comment: @Grundy, все верно, javascript начал осваивать сравнительно недавно и пока получается каша, даже странно, но эту задачу я без труда решил бы на php, но не получается в js...

Comment: @Other, я бы закрыл как дубликат: [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590458/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2/590486#590486) или [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590571/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-js/590626#590626)

Comment: Если Вы можете решить, напишите решение, перевести тут могут помочь.

Comment: @Other, или прибегут еще закрывальщики с криками - тут не бюро переводов :)

Comment: @Grundy, тут несколько другой вопрос, хотя, конечно, да, думаю второй лучше подходит.

Comment: @Other, ну они как бы каждый на свою часть вопроса отвечают

Comment: @Grundy, да ладно, если кто-то пошевелит мозгами и реализует алгоритм хоть как-то, то тут можно и снизойти.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48480/discussion-between-other-and-grundy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понадобится функция, сравнивающая объекты (поправьте, если какие-то ключи нужно игнорировать или сравнивать иначе):

```
function equals(a, b){
  for (var n in a)
    if (n != 'count' && a.hasOwnProperty(n) && (!b.hasOwnProperty(n) || a[n] != b[n])){
      return false;
    }

  for (var n in b)
    if (n != 'count' && !a.hasOwnProperty(n)){
      return false;
    }

  return true;
}
```

А затем:

```
obj.reduce((a, b) => (a.some(x => equals(x, b) && ++x.count) || a.push((b.count = 1, b)), a), [])
```

Без сокращений и стрелочных функций:

```
obj.reduce(function (a, b){
  if (!a.some(function (x){
    if (equals(x, b)){
      ++x.count;
      return true;
    }

    return false
  })){
    b.count = 1;
    a.push(b);
  }

  return a
}, []);
```