# Как в javascript перемещать элементы массива в FileList?

Tags: javascript

При загрузке на сайт фотографий эти фото отображаются в галереи. В галереи есть возможность перемещать фотки. Как сделать так, чтоб при перемещении фотки в списке эта же фотка меняла свое местоположение в списке массива, т.к. в базу данных фото сохраняются в такой последовательности, как они расположены в массива FileList`a.

```
let arrPhotoList = document.getElementById('uploadgallery').files;

let oldElPhoto = arrPhotoList[evt.oldIndex];
arrPhotoList[evt.oldIndex] = arrPhotoList[evt.newIndex];
arrPhotoList[evt.newIndex] = oldElPhoto;
```

Пробовал сделать таким методом, но FileList не позволяет перезаписывать элементы списка таким образом. Если вдруг в FileList'е нельзя делать такие манипуляции, тогда как можно отфильтровать массив файлов и записать его в `<input type="file" name="gallery[]" class="hidden" id="uploadgallery" accept="image/*" multiple>`

Comment: Изменять `FileList` - нельзя. Записать файл в `<input type="file">` - нельзя. Но можно создать свой массив на основе `FileList`, сделать необходимые манипуляции, сохранить с помощью `FormData`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , можете показать пример такой манипуляции?

Comment: Приведите пример, который у вас есть - мы его подправим.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , мой пример грубо говоря в коде вопроса. Там идет получение FileList'a с input'a и дальше нужно этот список отфильтровать, затем отправить на сервер. Но получая массив таким образом `Array.from(document.getElementById('uploadgallery').files)` я все равно не могу обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создаем пустой массив: `var arr = [];`
2. Сохраняем все загруженные фото в созданный массив `arr`.

   ```
   let files = document.getElementById('uploadgallery').files;
   for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
       if (!files[i].type.match('image.*')) {
           files.splice(i, 1);
       } else {
           arr.push(files[i]);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Перемещаем фото(элементы массива `arr`) в нужном нам порядке:

   `arr.splice(from, 1, arr.splice(to, 1, arr[from])[0]);`
4. Покуем данные в `FormData` и отправляем их на сервер, например через ajax:

   ```
   let fd = new FormData(this);
   if(arr.length > 0) {
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           fd.append('gallery[]', arr[i]);
       }
   }
   ```

P.s. спасибо за подсказку.

> Можно создать свой массив на основе FileList, сделать необходимые манипуляции, сохранить с помощью FormData. – Stepan Kasyanenko

Comment: второй пункт неправильный. Со splice в цикле нужно быть очень внимательным

Comment: третий пункт непонятно зачем нужен. Ты можешь сразу по нужным индексам вставлять элементы в момент собирательства

Comment: Во втором пункте `splice` нужен для того, чтоб удалять все загруженные файлы, которые не картинки. Третий пункт нужен лично в моем случае для того, чтоб перемещать фото до того, как они будут сохранены, но в принципе да, 3 пункт можно пропустить тем, кому это не нужно.

Comment: У `FileList` нет метода `splice` - это во-первых, во-вторых, ты так удаляешь не все ненужные элементы [пример ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587613/186999)